# How does python optimize "is c in str"?

Tags: python

I'm trying to understand why the below app yields the results it does. It contains 4 implementations of a "is this string a 'Pangram'". It seems that when doing a lookup for `if char not in s:`, it does something significantly faster than a simple iteration of the string. Is this documented somewhere on what optimizations are used for this operation? It seems this is the reason that `withShortCircutManual` is so much slower than `withShortCircut`.

```
import time
import string
import random

x = "".join([random.choice("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy") for _ in range(10000000)])

def test(label, func):
  start = time.time()
  res = func(x)
  end = time.time()
  duration = end - start
  print(f"{label} ({res}): {duration}ms")

def withSet(s):
  length = len(set(s))
  return length == len(string.ascii_lowercase)

def bespoke(s):
    low = s.lower()
    d = [0] * 26
    for l in low:
        d[ord(l) - 97] = 1
    
    for l in string.ascii_lowercase:
        if d[ord(l) - 97] == 0:
            return False
    return True

def withShortCircut(s):
  s = s.lower()
  for char in string.ascii_lowercase:
    if char not in s:
      return False
  return True

def isIn(char, s):
    for c in s:
        if c == char:
            return True

    return False

def withShortCircutManual(s):
  s = s.lower()
  for char in string.ascii_lowercase:
    if not isIn(char, s):
      return False
  return True
  
test("set", withSet)
test("bespoke", bespoke)
test("short circuit", withShortCircut)
test("short circuit manual", withShortCircutManual)
```

Results:

> set (False): 0.0755767822265625ms
> bespoke (False): 0.7335474491119385ms
> short circuit (False): 0.006622791290283203ms
> short circuit manual (False): 0.22708892822265625ms

Comment: "It seems that when doing a lookup for if char not in s:, it does something significantly faster than a simple iteration of the string." no, it doesn't (not in the simplest case of a single character, if `char` has multiple characters its a substring search of course and more complicated). But it does it **in compiled C code** not at the Python interpreter level. You aren't going to beat it in pure Python, at least not in CPython

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga So the gain is nothing to do with some nifty internal character count within the string, but is just that the compiled C code is going to be faster for the iteration?

Comment: @Rollie yes, that is correct. You can test this by timing strings of increasing length and verifying that the operation is still O(N). If there was a hidden "internal character count", this operation would be O(1). Note that while _you_ are using `char in string` to look for a single character, a more general use-case would be to look up entire sub-strings (`char` can be any length and `in` still works), and creating a map of all possible substrings of the string would be prohibitively expensive and complicated.

Comment: Yes, as @PranavHosangadi stated, it is still fundamentally a linear search, and this is easily verifiable empirically by testing it on strings of increasing length. Keeping a set of characters around with every string would optimize this particular case but cost tons of extra memory. Python `str` objects are *already* hefty (check out `import sys; print( sys.getsizeof("a"))`, that would make them almost unusable practically.

Comment: Cool thanks all :) Feel free to answer if you like, or if this is duple we can close